# getting many messages of a Table change in SQL with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datagridview, messagebox

I am Sending my `DataGridview` data to `SQL database`. I have created and initiate the connection. All working fine but when I have more than one raw in my `Datagridview`, I am getting more messages that means each and every raw getting me a successfully added I need to get only one message.

```
private void buttonsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  InvoiceNew myobj = new InvoiceNew();
  myobj.Invoicedate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
  myobj.Invoiceno = textBoxInvoiceNo.Text;
  myobj.Invoicetotal = Convert.ToDouble(textboxtotal.Text);
  myobj.Balance = 0.00;
  myobj.Paidammount = Convert.ToDouble(textboxtotal.Text);

  myobj.AddInvoiceHeader(myobj);

  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    InvoiceDetailNew myobjd = new InvoiceDetailNew();

    myobjd.Invoiceno = textBoxInvoiceNo.Text;
    myobjd.Itemcode = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    myobjd.Itemname = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    myobjd.Qty = 
        Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    myobjd.Unitprice = 
        Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    myobjd.Subtotal = 
        Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    myobjd.AddInvoiceDetail(myobjd);

    main_menu myobj1 = new main_menu();
    myobj1.Show();
    this.Hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here? You have this in a `for` loop, it's going to keep going until it gets to `i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` ...right? What's the problem with that?

Comment: yah but my issue is for each and every time i am getting success message, here i have given if data added to database it will open a new window but for every data row adding it is giving result

Comment: move " main_menu myobj1 = new main_menu();
    myobj1.Show();
    this.Hide();" outside the for loop?

Comment: yah better option, it is OK after moving but i need a message any how i need a notification of database value passed.

Comment: #Marvin Smit thanx that is perfectly working, just now done :D